# jQuery submit form on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big form that is split over 3 pages (each page is self contained i.e. only contain part of the form wrapped around form tags). I have page buttons so the user can navigate between pages e.g. page 1, page 2, page 3 and each page is loaded depending on a page variable in the url querystring i.e.

```
www.myurl.com?page=1
```

What I want to happen is that when the user clicks on the page button the form is submitted but also passed the page button clicked in a post/get (I don't mind which) value i.e. `next_page = page number clicked`

What is the best way to do this? I am using jQuery in my code so a solution using this would be good

Comment: Instead of moving from one page to another, would you be willing to consider using an in-page form, broken down into three separate panes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.page_button').click(function() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        var button = $(this);
        $postData = $('#my_form').serialize() + '&save=Save';
        $.post(url, $postData, function(data) {
            window.location.href = button.attr('href');
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use tab based form

read this [article](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/11-useful-jquery-tab-navigation-solutions)

**[personally prefer](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)**

Answer (score 0):

With this `$(window.location).attr('search')` you can find `page=1`
Put this value in a hidden like this

```
var hidden_value = $(window.location).attr('search');
$('form').append('<input type="hidden" value="'+hidden_value+'" name="page_number" />');
```

And finaly submit your form with `form.submit();`

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you do not only need to pass the page number to the next page but also regular data from a form? 
Why not have a hidden input which you set to next_page_number before the form is submitted?

This would be part of POST-Data on your next page then.